# Android Content provider. How to get all data by one request from contact book

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

Is it possible to retrieve all data from contact book by one request (phone number, email, first name, last name, photo, thumbnail). Right now I am running a separate request for a first and last name, a separate request for a phone number and a separate request for an email, and so on. Is it possible to get all this data in one request? Please help me.

Comment: Of course. You can put as many rows (with as many fields) in the matrix cursor as you want as result of a query().

Comment: Well i know hoe to deliver the data. I dont know how to retriee all that data from contact book. Your question is unclear. What is problematic?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

You're probably running your queries on Alias tables such as `CommonDataKinds.Phone` and `CommonDataKinds.Email`, but the actual data for all these tables is stored in a single table called `Data`.

So you should query directly on `Data` and use the MIMETYPE column to figure out the "type" of the current row you're iterating over.

Here's an example of getting name, email, phone.
You can add more mimetypes to the list to get more types of data.
I'm using a HashMap to keep a list of values for each contact-ID but you would probably want to create a custom `Contact` class and put that info in it.

```
Map<Long, List<String>> contacts = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();

String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3};

// query only name/emails/phones
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String mime = cur.getString(1); // type of data (name / phone / email)
    String data = cur.getString(2); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234

    String kind = "unknown";

    switch (mime) {
        case Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            kind = "phone"; 
            break;
        case StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            kind = "name";
            break;
        case Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            kind = "email";
            break;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + kind + " - " + data);

    // add info to existing list if this contact-id was already found, or create a new list in case it's new
    List<String> infos;
    if (contacts.containsKey(id)) {
        infos = contacts.get(id);
    } else {
        infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        contacts.put(id, infos);
    }
    infos.add(kind + " = " + data);
}
```